# What could be the reason two .RData files are the same size when opened but one is 282 KB while the other is 76 MB?

Tags: r

I currently have two .RData files, one of which is 282 KB, while the other is 76.1 MB. The objects inside are nearly identical as both the result of saving the same simulation but for a single different parameter. What perplexes me is that when I load the .RData file with 282 KB into `RStudio`, it expands to the same size as the one with 76.1 MB. Is there a reasoning behind why?

Comment: Are there any dot-vars in the Rdata files? They are not listed by default (with `ls`), so may not be obvious. What are the object types? Are any of them environments?

Comment: Another important piece of data is how large is the `RData` file when you save the objects in R after loading them.

Comment: Forgive me, but what is a dot-var? For both files they just contain large matrices. It seems that for the much smaller file, there is an operation that leaves the matrices with many many more zeros than that in the larger file. Could that be why?

Comment: "dot-vars" are any variables that start with a period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is that one of the two `RData` files is being compressed while the other is not.  From the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html) for `save`, describing the `compress` option:

> logical or character string specifying whether saving to a named file is to use compression. TRUE corresponds to gzip compression, and character strings "gzip", "bzip2" or "xz" specify the type of compression.

Compression would explain why the same data set has two different sizes.